# Structure of $A_4/H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, quotient-group

I was reading about $A_4$ and $S_4$ groups and I got curious about some of the subgroups. And if we have $H:= \{(),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$, how would I determine and how would the structure look like of the quotient group $A_4/H$ and is $A_4$ a simple group?

Comment: How many elements has $A_4/H$?

Comment: No, $A_4$ is not simple since $H$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

$H$ is normal and the corresponding factor group is cyclic of order three.

Comment: And how can I show that $H$ Is normal subgroup in that case?

Comment: For example by computing its three cosets and noticing that right cosets and left ones coincide.